# almu and gemu of orthogonal projections and reflections?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, reflection

Let *V*be an *m*-dimensional subspace of R^n. I have already found the eigenvalues of the nxn orthogonal projection matrix A onto V as 0 and 1 with respective eigenspaces V_perp. and V, and dimensions of m and n-m. Also, I found the eigenvalues of the nxn reflection matrix B "across" V as 1 and -1 with respective eigenspaces also of V and V_perp., also with dimensions m and n-m.

Out of that I'm certain of most except the n-m dimensions.

But now I have "What can you say about the eigenvalues' algebraic and geometric multiplicities?" I know that gemu(A, B) <= almu(A,B) and that A and B are diagonalizable iff sum(gemus(A,B))=n.

Unfortunately I dont see how these help me. I'm trying to think about the problem with n=3, and m=2, eg, for reference but I don't want to extrapolate.

Pls no extremely complicated answers: young'un here.

Advance thanks

Comment: Why are you uncertain about the $n-m$ dimensions? $V^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of an $m$-dimensional subspace in an $n$-dimensional space, so it must have dimension $n-m$ (since the scalar product with respect to which we are taking orthogonal complements is nondegenerate). Now you should recall the notion of a gemu (I've never heard that abbrevation before, but it is a good one) to immediately obtain the gemus for $0$ and $1$. To find the almus, you can then use the inequalities.

Comment: OK, so gemu(A)=dim(ker(A))=dim(V_perp)=n-m, but what do I get from.       n-m<=almu(A)? And so gemu(B)=dim(ker(B))=dim(V)=m, but again what does m<=almu(A) tell me about the almu? Alos can you go into detail about "the acalar product with respect to..."?

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by gemu(A); in my opinion gemu is a function of a matrix (here, $A$) and an eigenvalue (here, $0$ or $1$). Anyway, try to combine $n-m \leq \operatorname{almu}\left(A, 0\right)$ with $m \leq \operatorname{almu}\left(A, 1\right)$ and another inequality you know for the almus, to obtain an equality, not an inequality.

Comment: To answer your last question, I need to ask you back: how do you define $V^\perp$ ?

Comment: You should say that "almu" and "gemu" is an abbreviation for resp.  "algebraic multiplicity" and "geometric multiplicity"